# How to access an application which is in remote JBoss

Tags: jboss

I am running my application using JBoss which is in windows7. Now I want to access the same application from other system which is having Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I saw some posts in the internet and I can able to access the remote JBoss & my application. But I am not able to Login. I am getting this error in the console

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I don't know what is the issue. Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Jboss is started to listen in localhost (127.0.0.1). On your standalone.xml file you will find something like:

```
<interface name="public">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
```

So you can change your standalone.xml file replacing this 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0, or you can edit (in your jboss/bin directory) standalone.conf.bat file and at some point add to your JAVA_OPTS the option -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0, like:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0"
```

You can even add this property on the standalone.xml file.

Comment: thanks for reply. I am using JBoss 4.2.1 GA. I don't have standalone.conf.bat file in bin directory.

Comment: If you have Jbos 4.2.1 just start it with `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0` or replace 0.0.0.0 with your hostname or ip address.

Comment: I tried with -b 0.0.0.0. It is showing login page, but when I click on login button I am not able to logged in. It showing the above error in the console